# Print Server not working

Tags: router, ethernet, print-server

Help!  Using wired ethernet, I have a D-Link DP300-U print server connected to an HPLaserJet 2100M (parallel port) that will not work.  The print server is hooked up after a Linksys BEFSR41 router.  I cannot add the printer using any methods listed in the print server manual, nor can I access the print server's admin page using a browser.  I've been dealing with this problem for months now and no one has been able to solve it!!  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you ping the print server?

Comment: No, that's part of the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is somewhere in the connection between the print server and the computer you are trying to access it from. To diagnose this, try these steps:

- How is the print server connected to the router? Is both the server and your computer connected to LAN-ports on the router?
- Try looking in the router interface, look for something like "Attached devices", see if you can find something that could be your your print server there. If you find it, the IP to the server will probably be listed tougher with it.

Comment: The computer and printserver are both connected to lan ports on the router.  I can get into the router interface, and found an ip address for the printserver- which worked.  Will know in a minute if the printer is working now.